# Excel 2007,2010,2013, 2016 Create Addin Installer with Toolbar button to run macro

Tags: excel, macros, excel-addins, vba

I have an excel addin file (.xlam). It contains one funtion & one macro. I want to create installer/uninstaller with home-ribbon button to run my macro. My code works fine but I dont know to to make extra tab visible with a button to run my macro. I am a novice. Experts please help. This installer should work on Excel 2007, 2010, 2013 and later. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want ribbon tab & button through installer because I will distribute this file to 100 of my colleagues to use my macro with ease via a button.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is what you are looking for:
http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm

You can find instructions on how to create Ribbon-buttons manually and a utility that does it for you.

The XLAM file itself will be installed as normal, but you can indeed make the macro's available with their own Ribbon-buttons and menu's.

Courtesy to Ron de Bruin, as usual.